# ImportError when deploy web app on cloud platform, MS Azure

Tags: python, django, opencv, azure

I have a web app writing in Python using Django. And everything does fine in my computer(localhost). But when I deployed it to Azure, what I worried does happened, which is no library found in the cloud. 
This is what it showed:
ImportError at /
No module named cv2
Python Path: [u'D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Lib\site-packages',
 '.',
 'D:\Windows\SYSTEM32\python27.zip',

Before import opencv package, everything runs fine at the cloud. It seems that the cloud compiler didn't have openCV packages. Is there any way that I can add packages manually?

Comment: Hi, any updates yet?

Comment: Hello, sorry to comment this so lately. I did what you have suggested. This is the error I got. `Module use of python27.dll conflicts with this version of Python.` Obviously, the python version is still in 3.4. I used to change the version from 2.7 to 3.4 by changing the **runtime.txt**. However, the weird thing is now I change it back to 2.7, it seems no changes been done in the server side. And neither does the Application Setting in the web app configuration work.

Comment: You can try to build a new virtual environment with 2.7 version on local, then try to complete the application with my suggestion. After all, you deploy them to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

According the installation description at http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html, there are 2 main steps to install opencv lib, installing `numpy` lib and copying `cv2.pyd` file to your directory.

You can try to follow the following steps to add opencv package to your Azure Web Apps application.

1. Follow https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-flask-app/#web-app-development---windows---command-line to get your application to local via git, then add the `numpy` package to your application, generate your all dependencies to `requirements.txt` file.
2. Download the latest openCV release from https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/?source=typ_redirect and double-click to extract it.
3. Goto `opencv/build/python/2.7` folder, copy the `X86` version of the `cv2.pyd` to your local repository path. For example, you can create a lib folder named `libs` at your root directory for those packages can't be directly compiled on Azure. And copy the `x86` version `cv2.pyd` file to this folder.
4. Use git to deploy your application to Azure.
5. Add the lib path in the script where you all use the `cv2` package:

   ```
   import sys
   sitepackage = "D:\home\site\wwwroot\libs"
   sys.path.append(sitepackage)
   ```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.